# Configuring shared login for two models (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I got two models that have a login. Company and User. What I wish to accomplish is to have one shared login on the front page that logs you in, not one for Company and one for User.

I am also assuming I need to create certain parameters between those models. Such as check the uniqueness of the email you register with. To avoid a person registering on both models, and when logging in on the shared login it gets an error.

My train of though is that I either need to make the login check two tables. Or somehow merge email and password from both models into a new table, that also shows which model the email and password they are logging in with belongs to. That's my thought process so far.

However I have no clue where to start, or what the best practice is for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement STI (Single Table Inheritance). Just google it, there is a lot of examples.

Comment: they recommend it only for a sub-model. Not for two different types of model it seems. Hm.

Comment: If you have common attributes for Company and User class then you can move them to Account class. Company and User should inherit from the Account class. Then in your routes you need to set class_name for Devise.

    devise_for :users, {
      class_name: "Account"
    }